# Efficient Matrix Multiplication

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

"Suppose that A, B, and C are 3 × 4, 4 × 5, and 5 × 6 matrices of numbers, respectively. Is it more efficient to compute the product ABC as (AB)C or as A(BC)? Justify your answer by computing the number of multiplications of numbers needed each way."

This is from my Discrete Math review sheet. I have the answer, but I have no idea how to get there, and there is nothing in the slides from class. How do I begin to set this up? This class has jarred my thinking process, so an extremely simple explanation is welcomed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the multiplication of $M$ and $N$, with dimensions $m\times n$ and $n\times p$, respectively. The product is $m\times p$ and to compute each of its $mp$ entries, you need to multiply $n$ times and add. So $mnp$ multiplications and $mp$ summations.

For your case, $AB$ entails $60$ multiplications and $15$ summations. Then, $(AB)C$ entails $90$ multiplications $18$ summations. In total, $150$ multiplications and $33$ summations.

On the other hand, $BC$ entails $120$ multiplications and $24$ summations. Then, $A(BC)$ entails $72$ multiplications and $18$ summations. In total, $192$ multiplications and $42$ summations.

So $(AB)C$ is more efficient (if efficiency, as the question suggests, is defined as entailing fewer multiplications between 2 reals.)

**Remark 1**: the summations mentioned above do not always involve the same number of summands. For example, in $AB$, each sum is over $4$ numbers, whereas in $(AB)C$, each sum is over $5$ numbers. The question focuses on contrasting the number of multiplications anyway.

**Remark 2**: for what it's worth, the following code

```
n = 1000000;

s1 = 0;
s2 = 0;

parfor i = 1:n
    A = rand(3,4);
    B = rand(4,5);
    C = rand(5,6);
    tic; (A*B)*C; temp = toc; s1 = s1 + temp;
    tic; A*(B*C); temp = toc; s2 = s2 + temp;
end
s1
s2
```

in MATLAB always produces `s1` **bigger than** `s2`.

Comment: Note that [there are ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) of calculating products of matrices ([especially _very large_ matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm)) using fewer computations than the straight-forward, by-definition method.

Comment: Matlab implements highly optimized matrix multiplication techniques. Using it to analyze the naive multiplication is rather dangerous.

Comment: @user251257 I agreed. I suspected the question was too simplistic and misleading in its usage of "efficient" so that was why I checked. Anyway, the code was there to precisely illustrate that point and yours.

Comment: Ok, I understand the mn, np, and nmp part. How do you calculate the summation? And then the (AB)C part? Sorry if this was stated already, I still don't understand. @yurnero

Comment: @cparks10 The $(i,j)$ element of $MN$ is $\sum_{l=1}^nM_{i,l}N_{l,j}$ so you have to multiply $n$ times and then add those $n$ numbers together.

Answer (score 0):

how many operations?

$(AB)$, we multiply every element a row of $A$ by every element in a column of $B$ (4 multiplications), to generate each element in AB.  $AB$ is a $3\times 5$ matrix.  $4\cdot3\cdot 5 = 60$ multiplications (and $45$ additions)

$(AB)C$ it $60 + (3\cdot 5 \cdot 6) = 150$ multiplications.

$(BC)$ is $(4\cdot 5 \cdot 6) = 120$ multiplications. And $BC$ is a $4\times 6$ matrix.

$A(BC)$ is $120 + 3\cdot 4\cdot 6 = 192$ multiplications.

Comment: `very element in $A$ multiplies every element in $B$`: is that true? For example, $a_{11}$ will only mutiply with $b_{1*}$. Maybe you're thinking of $A\otimes B$.